# Cocos2d-X // hide Mouse / Pointer

Tags: c++, cursor, mouse, cocos2d-x

Im trying to hide the cursor in order to create my own cursor for clickable objects (or set the cursor to "clickable cursor") for Windows // Mac // Linux platforms

Im searching in Cocos2D-X API but I can't find anything [just HTML5 solutions], so I was thinking about directly call to an OpenGL function (glusetcursor(cursor)) but I can't find the function or I don't know what object should I get from Cocos2D-x in order to call that function

It should be easy but after spend an hour searching info, I can't find anything but this.

Comment: Got some code snippets?

Comment: @Kathir The problem is that I don't have any code that could works or just doesn't work, I don't have anything except HTML5 code `cc.canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";` but I can't find anything similar in Cocos2D-X API, I also have an OpenGL function but I don't know if there is a way to call it from Cocos2D `void glutSetCursor(int cursor);`